# WebDriverException 'unknown error: no element reference returned by script' when using element.click()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying automate UI testing using selenium '3.14.0' java '1.8.0_151'
Automation is running on standalone GUI and as plugin on another system in inner iframe
I have a label referring to hidden check box, partial elements you can see below..

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;

label {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 0 0 1.333333rem;
```

When clicking on the label from the standalone UI - it works fine, but when clicking on the same one when it's in the iframe of the containing system, I get:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: no element reference returned by script
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 78.0.3904.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 78.0.3904.11 javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 80eb99bb78d864bcd2a4c1d4205a5d1c
```

code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WEBDRIVER_WAIT_TIME_SEC);
WebElement plugin = getRemoteIframe(By.cssSelector(pluginIframeCss));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(plugin));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("my-id")));
element.click();//throws WebDriverException
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("my-id")));
element.click();//throws WebDriverException
```

be aware that I found the element with all attributes, element is visible and clickable and when trying to click on it from console(F12) it works, only click by code throws exception...

Is someone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to perform click operation with javascriptExecutor. May be the element overridden by some other webElement.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

Comment: wait for elementToBeClickable(By.id("....")) and visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("....")) returned the element and even-though click()  failed...

Comment: clicking by JavascriptExecutor is working fine, but do you think that I must use it? no  solution for using element.click()?

Comment: Yes,  We can use javascriptExecutor whenever any element is overriden or hidden with some other DOM object. That's why the functionality is given

Answer (score 1):

If your **element** is inside an **iframe** you have to switch to the iframe first like this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
```

then you can do whatever you want with that **element**

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("my-id")));
element.click();
```

Comment: sure, I got into the iframe - if I wasn't in I would get noSuchElementException

Comment: can you please write your code in a more complete way?

Comment: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WEBDRIVER_WAIT_TIME_SEC);
WebElement plugin = getRemoteIframe(By.cssSelector(pluginIframeCss));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(plugin));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(ID)));
element.click();

Comment: I get the exception in element.click() - edited code block in question  for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this problem is occurring. But you can try using Action Class.

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action clickLabel =  builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"))).click().build();
clickLabel.perform();

More info on
https://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html

Although the issue is not related to this  : Selenium version you mentioned is quite old. You can try with latest : 3.141.59

Comment: Tried your answer but failed on same exception...
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(by)).click().build().perform()
throws: unknown error: no element reference returned by script
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)

Will try upgrade to latest selenium version...